# Where to put a base html template in Django

Tags: django, django-templates

I have six apps that share a common base html (`base.html`) template. My question is which should contain that `base.html`? Or should the project template directory contain that `base.html`? I am using Django version 1.10.

Comment: Yes, usually best practice to put in the templates directory of your project at the first level of that directory.

Comment: @AaronLelevier that will make an app less reusable? Will need to install the project template to other projects using apps depending on base template.

Comment: In the projects that I have worked on, we've usually put base templates in another app called core. Works well for us.

Comment: @Devone maybe I misunderstood the question then.  Okay, I agree with #denvaar on having a "core" app for shared functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to put it in the project's templates directory.